# JSON_Spirit: good examples of unpacking a JSON string?

Tags: c++, json, json-spirit

Any good examples/tutorials of unpacking JSON strings with the C++ JSON_Spirit library?

Something that can traverse a json_spirit::Value object and pretty-print it would be ideal.